# Parse json files in kakfa

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Hi I am trying to read 1000 JSON files through kafka and process it into spark streaming.

My JSON format looks like this.

```
{
"name" : "The Lightning Thief",
"author" : "Rick Riordan",
}
```

I want to read all the json files and calculate the repeated authors and repeated names.Like this.

Author Rick Riordan : 7
   Name Jessie : 12

This is my code.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{ StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType };
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig
object StructuredStreamingExample {

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("JSON Reader").master("local").getOrCreate();
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
  ssc, kafkaParams, Set("TutorialTopic"))
stream.foreachRDD(
  rdd => {
    val dataFrame = sqlContext.read.json(rdd.map(_._2)) 

  })
 }
}
```

But I dont know to proceed further.Any help will be appreciated.